# Any replacement for IAutomaticUpdates :: pause in Windows 10?

Tags: winapi

In earlier versions of Windows this paused automatic updates:

```
    IAutomaticUpdates *automaticUpdates = 0;
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AutomaticUpdates, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IAutomaticUpdates, (void**)&automaticUpdates);
    if (automaticUpdates != NULL)
    {
        hr = automaticUpdates->Pause();
    }
```

According to MSDN, "IAutomaticUpdates::Pause is no longer supported. Starting with Windows 10 Insider Preview calls to Pause always return S_OK, but do nothing."  [IAutomaticUpdates::Pause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

We don't want Windows Update interrupting our program.  Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: Updates are always on in Windows 10, by order of Redmond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Windows 10 a bunch of settings are no longer available. Here the settings of the update service are now no longer free to set by the user.

Because you need administrative rights to even call Pause, you may stop the Windows Update Service at all. But this is a very harsh way to prevent the update service to interrupt you. I wouldn't recommend this a a real practical solution for me. But it may help you.